# Handlebarsjs : H1 tag won't display when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm messing around with Handlebars.js and I'm doing a very simple example consisting of a tutorial from a website(the shoes section) and my own simple little template(the heading, where the problem is)

**handlebardemo.html**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Handlebar demo</title>

    <script src="lib/jquery-2.1.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="lib/handlebars-v4.0.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
</head> 
<body>
<div class="username-container">
    <script id="heading-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
        <h1 class="h1">Hello {{username}}</h1>
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <button type="submit" id="username-submit">Enter</button>
</div>

<h4 class="w3-row-padding">Shoe List:</h4>
<ul class="shoesNav w3-ul w3-text-indigo"></ul>
<script id="shoe-template" type="x-handlebars-template">
    {{#each this}}
        <li class="shoes"><a href="/{{name}}">{{name}}--Price:{{price}} </a></li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
</body>
```

**main.js**

```
$("#username-submit").click(function(){
    var uNameVal = $("#username").val();
    var uName = {"username":uNameVal};

    var theTemplateScript = $("#heading-template").html();
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
    $(".username-container").append(theTemplate(uName));
});

$(function (){
    var shoesData=[{name:"Nike", price:199.00}, {name:"Loafers", price:59.00}, {name:"Wing Tip", price:259.00}];

    //Get html from tempalte in script tag
    var theTemplateScript = $("#shoe-template").html();

    //Compile the template
    var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
    $(".shoesNav").append(theTemplate(shoesData));
    //shoesData is passed to compiled handlebars function
    //function inserts values from the objects in their respective places in the HTML
    //and returned HTML: as a string. Then jQuery is used to append the resulting HTML string to the page
})
```

Im not sure if I'm using the handlbars syntax etc. correctly, but i based it mostly off of the second function in main.js, which came from a brief handlebars tutorial

When I click the Enter button, nothing happens. There are no console errors, it just does nothing. Am I going about this the wrong way, at least compared to the unordered list example?

EDIT: As per Elli Parks answer, I added an id to the submit button and changed the click handler assignment to the submit button rather than the textbox(a silly mistake on my part). The element still won't appear when the submit button is clicked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **main.js**, you're attaching the click handler to `#username`, which is an input field. You need to give the Enter button an id (ex: `#username-submit`) and attach the click handler to the button.

So something like this:

**handlebardemo.html**

`<button type="submit" value="Enter" id="username-submit" >Enter</button>`

**main.js**

```
$("#username-submit").click(function(){

   var uNameVal = $("#username").val();
   var uName = {"username":uNameVal};

   var theTemplateScript = $("#heading-template").html();
   var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
   $(".username-container").append(theTemplate(uName));

});
```

Comment: ok, that was a glaring error lol. I changed this but it still doesn't display the H1 element

Comment: do you have the click handler within `$( document ).ready(function() {}`?

Comment: I do not, I'll try this out

Comment: Ok that totally worked, thanks. Looks like my jQuery is the problem rather than Handlebars

Comment: Hi Elli, seems we've had a bit of overlap :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things:

- fix the selector to target the button, like @ElliPark has already said
- put the whole thing into the document-ready handler (ie, into the `$(function () {...} );` construct. You are trying to attach the event listener before the DOM is ready.

See the [demo on JSBin](http://output.jsbin.com/suxiri).